# Highlight current date in a custom google sheet calendar

Tags: google-sheets, calendar, conditional-formatting

Is there any formula for conditional formatting that can highlight today's date in the google sheet calendar posted below? I'm struggeling to write one myself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOVbq.png

Answer (score 0):

Just use the conditional formatting with this custom formula:

```
=today()=A1
```

if you are setting the conditional format for the range starting with the cell A1

Comment: Hi, doesn't seem to work. I suspect conditional formatting need to understand how to connect correct day number with correct month when highlighting

Comment: You must add the dates to the calendar cells. Ie, if it is 1. January, add 1/1/2022 into the cell. Then format the cell so that only the day part is displayed (use Format>Number>Custom data and time). Repeat that process for each of the calendar cells.